# Improve my permissions to access on my API responses with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I build an application with Laravel as API. This is my first API.

I have a "Team" model or there are several users who are part of it.

I use [mpociot/teamwork](https://github.com/mpociot/teamwork) to manage it all.

Many of my models have `team_id to be linked to a team.

On each function in my controllers, I do this to manage permissions :

```
$my_model = Model::find($model_id);

if (Auth::user()->currentTeam->id == $my_model->team_id) {
    // LOGIC
    return response()->json(204);
} else {
    return response()->json(401);
}
```

It’s very annoying to do this every time. I know there are middleware but I don't see how to access each model like that ...

Do you have an idea to improve my code?

Comment: How do you get `$model_id` ? From the request ?

Comment: @Ersoy no, from the URL

Comment: `$model_id = $request->route('id');` inside the middleware - and rest of the code will be copied to there.